# Using D3 Drag on grouped elements

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to use the d3.behavior.drag function to drag & the text/shapes to a different position. Eventually, I wish to save the variables of the new position when it is moved from its original place into a SQL DB run by Ruby on rails.

However, at the moment when I've tried my current code, the text/shapes do not move, instead seem to replicate on the same position:

```
         var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
                      .origin(Object)
                      .on("drag", function(d) {
                        d.x = d3.event.x;
                        d.y = d3.event.y;
                       draw();
                    });
```

Then I have a function 'draw' for my text/shapes & positions

```
                  function draw() { 

               // code is within here - check fiddle

                 }

                  draw()
```

I was beginning to believe that it wasnt working because I'm using translate instead of x & Y within my objects:

```
                var node= [ {name:'amy', country: 'USA', 'translate:"translate(190,83)"}]
```

Some examples ive seen have this instead:

```
              var node= [ {name:'amy', country: 'USA', x: 100, y:0}]
```

I have also tried this way, but when I drag the shape it leaves a trail of repeating shapes.

I would appreciate if someone could explain why this is happening/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the translate to x, and y for all the nodes and Change

```
node= node.enter().append("g")
                .call(drag)
```

to

```
   node.enter().append("g")
            .call(drag)
           .attr('class', 'node');
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zc4z9/5/

You might want to review this bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218 to make sure you understand .enter() [as well as .transition() and .exit()]

Comment: You are getting the bold looking elements because new shapes and text are being added each time you drag. The multiple, layered elements makes the text look bold. It can be fixed by modifying your drag function so it changes the position of the g.node elements without calling draw() again. Look at lines 57 and 58: http://jsfiddle.net/Zc4z9/8/